# how use php query in AJAX jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Normally this script shows the title and content related to a post but I want to use custom `content.php` for post format.

> Is there any way to use   **get_template_part('content');** in this
>   script ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.br').click(function () {
            jQuery('.contents').remove();
            var checked = jQuery('#test').serialize();

            jQuery.ajax( {

                url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",

                data: "action=call_post&" + checked,

                success: function (obj) {

                    var render_data = "<div class='contents'>";
                    // This is to watch your json object
                    console.log(obj);
                    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        console.log(obj[i].post_title);
                        render_data += " <h4>" + obj[i].post_title + "</h4>";
                        render_data += "<p>" + obj[i].post_content + "</p>";
                    }
                    render_data += "</div>";
                    jQuery(render_data).appendTo('.mobile_brand');
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

> Function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_call_post', 'call_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_post', 'call_post');
function call_post()
{
$params = wp_parse_args ( $_REQUEST, array(
  'mobile' => 'some-default-brand',
  'template' => '',

));

$brand = $params['mobile'];
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'brand',
            'value' => $test, 
        ) ,
    ) ,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if( ! empty ($params['template'])) {
  $template = $params['template'];

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
   while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  $query->the_post();
 get_template_part($template);
 }
 } 

  die();

} else {
  wp_send_json($query->posts);

}
}
```

> content.php

```
    <div <?php post_class( 'col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 ' ); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <div class="single-post"> 

                        <div class="post-thumb" > 
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail  ( 'large', array(
                                    'class' => 'img-responsive' 
                            ) ); ?> 
                            </a>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="post-info"> 
                            <div class="post-title">
                            <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                            </div>
                        <div class="rs"><p><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price1', true ); ?>
        <?php _e( '', 'mobilewebsite' ); ?></p></div>
                        </div>                          
                    </div>                                 
                </div>
<?php $item_number++;
 if( $item_number % 2 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>';
 if( $item_number % 4 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>';
 if( $item_number % 6 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>'; 
 if( $item_number % 6 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>'; 
 ?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be constructing HTML out of strings in javascript, it opens you up to XSS attacks, use dom nodes or a templating languages instead to build the markup instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the PHP associated with the AJAX action `call_post`. If you want to return different data, you should pass a parameter in the request that you handle later;

`data:"action=call_post&template=custom&"+checked,`

Ideally, you could just return the data rendered from php with a flag

`data:"action=call_post&template=custom&format=html&"+checked,`

From a PHP perspective, you would find your parameters in `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`.

---

> Scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.br').click(function () {
            jQuery('.contents').remove();
            var checked = jQuery('#test').serialize();

            jQuery.ajax( {

                url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",

                data: "action=call_post&template=content&" + checked,

                success: function (result) {

                    jQuery(result).appendTo('.mobile_brand');
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

> functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_call_post', 'call_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_post', 'call_post');

function call_post()
{
    $params = wp_parse_args ( $_REQUEST, array(
      'mobile' = 'some-default-brand',
      'template' = '',
    ));

    $brand = $params['mobile'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'brand',
                'value' => $brand, 
            ) ,
        ) ,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if( ! empty ($params['template'])) {

      $template = $params['template'];

      // loop through your query here and render the HTML using $template

      // ...

      // then kill the request

      die();

    } else {

      // or send back the posts as json

      wp_send_json($query->posts);

    }
}
```

Comment: // loop through your query here and render the HTML using $template,,,, i add loop here but nothing show result. can u plz explain how content.php attached to it from my theme folder.

Comment: Post the code that you attempted, please

Comment: You need to do a WP loop for that function to work. https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: i also try WP loop that way but not work,, look at updated function.php

Comment: Replace 'content' with $template. The idea is that you are dynamically requesting the template part to use, not hard-coding it.

Comment: and what will be the name of content.php in theme folder. if replacing content to $template in loop?

Comment: Did you set the template to load in the AJAX call? `data: "action=call_post&template=custom-content-here&" + checked,`

Comment: what function.php will be. if i want to add some others key and there value in filter..  if others key are price, ram and feature ?

Comment: Whatever you put in `$data` in JS, comes through in `$_REQUEST` on the PHP side. Put your default values in [`wp_parse_args`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args) and access via `$params`